# Reset password Lenovo Z50 by Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor - hibernated session

Tags: windows-8, passwords, hibernate

I lost my password in Lenovo Z50 in Windows 8.1. I tried to reset it by program Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor. After I selected disk partition the message which I saw was:

Selected 1

Mounting from `/dev/sda5`, with filesystem type NTFS
So, let's really check if it is NTFS?

```
The disk contains an unclean file system <0, 0>
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.

NTFS: Yes but hibernated
============================================
** The system is HIBERNATED!
** SAFEST is to boot into windows and shut down properly!
=============================================
if that is not possible, you can force changes,
but the hibernated session will be lost!

Do you wish to force is? (y/n)
```

And even If tried to force it didn't work. I tried to put out the battery and then use program but stil doesn't work.
What can I do to "shut it down properly" or any other way to reset the password? I tried to find the answer in the internet but I found nothing. Please help me asap

Comment: Can't you use a windows disk & boot into a "safe mode" or "repair" to cancel the hibernation / shutdown normally? (Or do something when resuming like hold shift or similar?)

Answer (score 2):

Simply booting into a repair disk won't work because it still keeps the hibernation image on the disk.

Instead, normally boot the system into the Windows drive until you reach the password screen, and can't go any further.

Then, you can shut down using your preferred method without the need of a password. If all else fails, your "preferred method" can be holding down the power button and force shutdown... booting into the Offline Password Editor from that point should not display the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using a boot disk of choice delete the "hiberfil.sys" file on the root of the OS partition, restart and boot into windows then shut down at the password screen, then try your password reset disk.